# Ebay Analytics api Get a Traffic Report return The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, analytics, ebay-api, bad-request

Hi I am working with ebay analytics api. I am trying to get ebay listing impressions but my code return The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. I have tried many times but i can not solved this problem.
My code is below:

```
string response1 = "";
string response2 = "";
try
  {
   string url = "";
   url += "https://api.ebay.com/sell/analytics/v1/traffic_report?";
   url += "filter=marketplace_ids:%7BEBAY_US%7D,";
   url += "listing_ids:%7Bxxxxxxxxxxxxx%7D,";
   url += "date_range:%5B20170201..20170227%5D&";
   url += "dimension=LISTING&";
   url += "metric=LISTING_IMPRESSION_SEARCH_RESULTS_PAGE,LISTING_IMPRESSION_STORE,SALES_CONVERSION_RATE&";
  url += "sort=LISTING_IMPRESSION_STORE";

 HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);     httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
 httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
 HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
 response1 = "StatusCode:"+httpResponse.StatusCode + ",StatusDescription:" + httpResponse.StatusDescription + ",ResponseUri:" + httpResponse.ResponseUri;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  response2 = "Message:" + ex.Message;

}
string resp = response1 + "==" + response2;
```

Into url "xxxxxxxxxx" is my product ItemID

Please tell me what is the exact reason.
Please any one help me.
I am waiting for solution.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried to run the url within browser?

Comment: Yes I also tried . But return response {
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorId" : 1002,
    "domain" : "OAuth",
    "category" : "REQUEST",
    "message" : "Missing access token",
    "longMessage" : "Access token is missing in the Authorization HTTP request header."
  } ]
}